# Android studio switch layouts using buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

My question its very simple, how can I switch between layouts using buttons in each layouts?
Layout1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_polygon"
    app:iconTint="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Layout2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:text="Back"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The buttons:

```
btn_1= findViewById(R.id.button);
btn_2= findViewById(R.id.button1); 

btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
            }
});
btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
            }
        });
```

The first button works fine, but the seconds doesnt.
I have tried inflate the view as well:

```
view_2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
btn_2 = view_2.findById(R.id.button2);
```

I need to add more details, so, here I am.
I am want to switch layout using buttons, indeed the first button change the layout, but when I already change the layout I cannot use the other button to "return" to the first layout. Its suppose to look like a menu.

Comment: Shouldn't it be button1 calls layout2 and viceversa? I guess layout1 is the first one to show

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the content view with a button using setcontent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946098/how-to-change-the-content-view-with-a-button-using-setcontent)

Comment: In the code is as you say, I had copied it swaped, I edit it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many tests, it is best to use another application or fragments, where you can create another layout and change it without problems.